# Android sql insert query

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I have a little problem with inserting data in sqlite in Android. I wrote a method which do that with `ContentValues`,but it's not working properly. Here is the method :

DatabaseHelper.class

```
public boolean executeQuery(String tableName,String keys,Object value){
    return execQuery(tableName,keys,value);
}

private static boolean execQuery(String tableName,String key,Object value){
    sqliteDb = instance.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(key, value.toString());
    sqliteDb.insert(tableName, null, values);

    return true;

}
```

And I'm using this like that :

```
dbHelper.executeQuery("users", "seed", seed); // string
dbHelper.executeQuery("users", "id", id); // int
dbHelper.executeQuery("users", "name", name); // string
dbHelper.executeQuery("users", "lang", lang); // string
```

And the problem is that I this method insert all values as single row in database,but I want all data to be a part of one row.

What I have to do to get the things to work correctly? 
I'm not really good with sqlite,so please excuse me if my question is a little silly...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    private static boolean execQuery(String tableName,String seed,String id,String name, String lang){

    sqliteDb = instance.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("seed", seed);
        values.put("id", id);
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("lang", lang);

    sqliteDb.insert(tableName, null, values);
return true;
    }

dbHelper.executeQuery("users",seed,id, name,lang); // string
```

**EDITED**

```
 private void execQuery(String tableName,ContentValues val)
 {
    sqliteDb = instance.getWritableDatabase();       
    sqliteDb.insert(tableName, null, val);
    return true;
 }
```

**call**

```
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("seed", seed);
        values.put("id", id);
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("lang", lang);
   dbHelper.executeQuery("users",values); // string
```

Comment: That's ok,but If I want to use this method to insert data in other tables too,which don't have this rows?Is there a way to put key-value,without writing all of them as params in method head section?

Comment: ya use can create a seperate string array for different different tables 
like String[] fieldtable={"seed","id","name","lang"};

private static boolean execQuery(String tableName,String[] field, String seed,String id,String name, String lang

Comment: just pass the contentvalues as parameter in your method

Answer (score 2):

You should use the same `ContentValues` object to add all your desired columns. Like this:

```
    Content values= new ContentValues();
    values.add("seed",seed);
    values.add("id",id);
    values.add("name",name);
    values.add("lang",lang);
    sqliteDb.insert(tableName,null,values);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass string key array and Object array

```
dbHelper.executeQuery("users", /*Array of seed,id,name,lang*/, /*Object Array of their value*/); 


and use 
values.put(key[i], value[i].toString()); for all i=0 to n
```